# SSRS Split table to multiple pages and repeat header/footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am making an Invoice in SSRS. 
What I want is to repeat the header (Customer info, Number etc) on all pages, and split the items to multiple pages if there are too many items in tablix.

How can I achieve this in SSRS

What I have tried now is to move all other details to header/footer using expressions. It works good, but the header doesn't support autogrow. The information seems to be clipped when the customer address is more than 3 lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "if it's too much."?

Comment: @Mazhar Question edited

Comment: Also.could you share what kind of output you are expecting.. like Excel, pdf etc? Also a screen shot would be more descriptive..

Comment: I am afraid that will make the question complicated. 
In short, I want to adjust the height of header dynamically as per the content inside it.